# React Router - Nested links redirecting to custom 404 page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a built a simple react router project in which "Topics" page/component has nested links "one", "two", "three" and then a Route mapping to component "Topic" which renders content with `match.params.id`, but its redirecting to custom not found page,

Here's the link to codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-routing-ecdwt

Comment: topics one, two and three are they going to be additional components or external sites?

Comment: another additional component called "Topic" should be displayed, instead displaying notFoundPage component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have specified `exact` property in `/topics` route.

You can specify route like this:

```
<Route path="/topics/:topicId" component={SingleTopic} />
// /topics/one
// /topics/two
// /topics/three
```

In `SingleTopic` component you can get specified topic id by `this.props.match.params.topicId` and then load requested topic.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Url does change to topics/one, topics/two or topics/three when clicked but the component being displayed is of NotFoundPage

Comment: i would say, component "Topic" is not displayed at all when clicked on links one, two, three

Comment: delete exact prop from topics route

Comment: why is that happening, i require exact when i mention this route inside routes.js page <Route path={`topics/:id`} component={Topic} />

Comment: I think you shouldn't add exact when you are using parameters inside route